# How to run mongodb connector in Kafka?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have downloaded a binary Kafka's files then Jar file of conector. Then specified the path to connector jar and configured config file with connection to mongo.

After I have laucnhed zookkepper, run Kafka and created topic. How to lauch connector source?

Answer (score 0):

There are `connect-standalone` and `connect-distributed` scripts in the Kafka bin folder for running Kafka Connect.

You'll also need to edit the respective properties files to make sure the Mongo connector plugin gets loaded